# Instalação de dependências adiciona dependências a mais

Tags: php, composer

É a primeira vez que estou tentando trabalhar com o `composer`, o propósito é usar apenas o `PHPUnit`, pois não uso mais nenhuma dependência. Ao instalar o `composer`, com o `composer.json` tendo apenas o `PHPUnit` como dependência, ele ainda assim instala outras dependências como:

- symfony
- doctrine
- phpspec
- sebastian
- phpdocumentor

Não sei se eles são obrigatórios no `composer` ou se ele é 'intruso' e instala isso sempre. Já ouvi falar de algumas dessas dependências, mas nunca usei e não sei como usar. Para que cada uma delas serve no projeto? É possível deletadas? Como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O pacote [PHPUnit](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit) para funcionar precisa de alguns outros pacotes (dependencias).

Na especificação [do seu pacote](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit) são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer dúvida entre no [site correspondente de gerenciador de pacotes](https://packagist.org/) no pacote [PHPUnit](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit). Alguns são bibliotecas próprias do PHP e outros são pacotes como por exemplo: [symfony/yaml](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/yaml)

Só lembrando que sem esses pacotes adicionais o pacote principal não funciona. Tem outro fator também a observar que esses outros pacotes podem ter seus próprios pacotes para funcionar também.!

Observe o item *`requires`* do pacote (package), o item determina as dependencias do pacote.

Comment: Ah, não sabia desse detalhe, no caso, há outros como o doctrine que não são dependências do PHPUnit, mas podem ser dependências de outros né?

Comment: @Ivcs isso mesmo tudo é um lógica aonde um depende do outro. Porque isso traz a não repetição de código e um uso já que está pronto do outro. E muito interessante e perfeito a lógica. No mundo .NET, JAVA, etc é assim também